# Is HttpServletRequest deleted in any step of the comunication process between server and client?

Tags: java, request, struts-1

I have two methods. Method1 creates ActionErrors and it does a findForward() to Method2; then Method2 findForward() to a jsp.

```
public ActionForward method1(ActionMapping mapping,ActionForm form,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
   //stuff
   ActionErrors errors = new ActionErrors();
   errors.add("myError", new ActionError("myError"));
   saveErrors(request, errors);   
   return mapping.findForward(method2);
}

//...
//properly configured struts config file
//...

public ActionForward method2(ActionMapping mapping,ActionForm form,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
  //stuff
  return mapping.finForward(myJsp);
}
```

**EDIT 1:**
I was confused when asked the previous question. So I'll arrange it asking another to clarify myself ^^'.
I know 3 ways to call a method from another:

1. mapping.findForward("method2"):

   `< forward name="method2" path="/path/to/method2"/>`
2. return to another method:

   ```
   public ActionForward method1(ActionMapping mapping,ActionForm form,HttpServletRequest request,HttpServletResponse response) {
           //stuff   
           return method2(mapping, form, request, response);
   }
   ```

   3. From jsp using ajax or whatever

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. `findForward` looks at the action mapping and returns it. What happens after that depends on what that action mapping actually *is*. If, say, it's a `redirect` then sure--redirects are new requests so whatever is in the current one will go away. You can't "forward to a method".

Comment: Coding name conventions and naming misconception are mostly implied here in your question. But probably the action config is what you should explore to get more options to control the flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the request is lost in the server when sending response to the client.